# Rails :overwrite_params with nested parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the :overwrite_params option in link_to helper. But I have problems overwriting nested parameters values. Here some code:

With:

```
link_to book_item.editorial, :overwrite_params  => {:filter => {[editorials.id] => book_item.editorial.id.to_s}}
```

The complete `params[:filter]` value is replaced (ie. I lost `params[:filter][:author]` value)

If I use:

```
link_to book_item.editorial, :overwrite_params  => {'filter[editorials.id]' => book_item.editorial.id.to_s}
```

I don't lost values, but if `params[:filter][:editorials]` exists in the url, another `params[:filter][:editorials]` is attached, so I don't get any overwrite.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Giving a looong shot here.
Can you try this:

```
link_to book_item.editorial, :overwrite_params  => { :filter => params[:filter].merge({[editorials.id] => book_item.editorial.id.to_s}) }
```

Then you'd probably need to initialize params[:filter] somewhere, to make sure you don't run `nil.merge()`

Just do

```
params[:filter] ||= {}
```

somewhere in your code.

Once again, that's probably not the best solution.
Hopefully it will help you figure something out or keep moving until someone gives a better answer :)